# Create my own text based data storage

Tags: java, database, file-io

I need to store maybe 250 million records of String -> String mappings and a database seems overload for this sort of thing.

I can't store this in memory as it will run out of heap space. I could extend the heap space, but I'd prefer not to do this.

I want as fast access as I can get to a single mapping as possible and wanted to know the best way to go about this.

The initial String is unique and what I will be searching by. I also know the range the string length will lie in, but its mapped value could be any length.

Is it possible to get something as fast as a database for searching? I'm guessing not but just wanted to be sure.

I'm working in Java, but I assume this will be language independent.

Comment: to me for 250 million records, a database doesn't seem like 'overload'. I would go with a db

Comment: You realize that as soon as you move your data from memory to a file the speed is going to be orders of magnitude lower, right?

Comment: When database is overload, do you think you can handle it in plain file system?

Comment: If you 250,000,000 records with each record having just 10 characters, you will get at least a 2,500,000,000 byte file which translates to about 2.3 GB - bad idea for a text file - use a DB

Comment: @Ben: what about what are *made of* your 250 million strings?  Are these dictionary words? ATGC sequences? Some custom encoding? Depending on what the string may contain there *may* be super-efficient representation way more efficient than simply putting your strings as is in disk-based a key/value store.  You'd need to tell what the strings are made of (what is your "alphabet") and what are the possible "words" (even if they're not real words) that can be made with that alphabet.

Comment: *"Is it possible to get something as fast as a database for searching?"*...  As fast as a database doesn't mean much: in-memory databases do run around circles disk-based ones.  So if you manage to put your 250 million strings in a memory-based DB, you'd be way faster than if you don't.  What about memory?  32 GB of RAM is about three-billing consultant hours... Is this something going to run on a single server?  Then add memory, memory and more memory and instantiate a big fat JVM and "compact" these strings and make it all fit in memory : )

Comment: The index Strings are usernames essentially. So I can put restrictions on the alphabet and length, but keeping them in a sorted order is going to be difficult as they are added and removed regularly. The reason I don't want to mess with the Java Heap space is that I may wish to downgrade/upgrade the server at any point (strange as that sounds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis http://redis.io/ is what you need!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use an already existing key-value store like Voldemort, CouchDB or Cassandra?  There are so many existing projects, why write a new one?

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Well it's kind of an answer - software doing that already exists, go use it.